# Better way to write this popup function?

Tags: javascript

```
function popUp(URL) {
    day = new Date();
    id = day.getTime();
    eval("page" + id + " = window.open(URL, '" + id + "', 
       'toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=400,height=600,left=600,top=300');");
}

<a href="javascript:popUp('http://google.com')">Open the Popup Window</a>
```

That is the code I have now. I want to change it so that it targets a specific class like "popup" and all links with that class generates a popup window with the link in the `href`.

Kind of like this:

```
<a class="popup" href="http://google.com">Open the Popup Window</a>
```

How would I achieve this?

Comment: Why the `eval`? That's completely unnecessary. Use an array if you really need to create a programmatically-named variable.

Comment: I need the window to be a specific size. It will contain lyrics to a song.

Comment: How does that equate to `eval` being required? What do song lyrics have to do with it?

Comment: Instead of `eval` you can say `window["page" + id] = window.open(...)`, or, better, `myNonGlobalPageList["page" + id] = window.open(...)` - I'm not sure what your comment has to do with Tomalak's comment on `eval`.

Comment: Sorry, that comment was directed towards another commenter who deleted his comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
 function popUp(URL){
day = new Date();
    id = day.getTime();
      window.open(URL,'"+id+"','toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=400,height=600,left=600,top=300');
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The best optimisation is to remove it, let visitors decide if they want to open the link in a new window or not. At the very least, move the code to a listener:

```
<a href="http://google.com" onclick="return popUp(this.href);">Open the Popup Window</a>
```

Then in the popup function, return false if the function executes correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to be tardy to the party, but here's my 2 cents:

With jquery to do your example

```
<a class="popup" href="http://google.com">Open the Popup Window</a>
```

you could use:

```
var page = [], id=0;
$('.popup').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
 // add to array of open popups
page.push(window.open(this.href,"page"+id,'toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=400,height=600,left=600,top=300')); 
     id++;
    return false;
});
```

Then you'd use something like this to close popups in order they were opened.

```
$('button').click(function(e){
   page.reverse();
   page.pop().close(); 
   page.reverse();
});
```